# How to determine if existing AWS Cognito user pool is case sensitive?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I have an existing user pool (I don't know who created it) and I'm wanting to know if this was created with the case sensitivity option set for username/email.  I can't find this information in the console and the things I've read indicate that this option is only available on creation of a new user pool.

Does anyone know how to figure out if this pool is set for case sensitivity?

I ask because we see that logins where the sign in email has different casing than the email in cognito are failing.

Comment: Use the CLI - `aws cognito-idp describe-user-pool --user-pool-id <USER POOL ID>`.  It will be under `UsernameConfiguration.CaseSensitive`

Comment: That is the answer every time you cannot do something in the UI: use the CLI.

Comment: @luk2302 AWS does not include all available API calls in the console

Comment: @GlenCarpenter in the CLI they do. Please give a counter example.

Comment: @luk2302 that is what I mean, they are all available in the CLI, but not available in the console

Comment: I tried the CLI command described above and do not see a UsernameConfiguration section at all...